# I am developing a webpage on codepen and would like to include an image stored on my device on my webpage. What do I put as the image source?

Tags: html, css, image, src

The image is in a folder "more" which is in a folder "Pictures" which is in "My PC".

Comment: You could spin up a local server, get the public IP etc... (but you IP is going to change eventually...) Not sure you wanted to do this though ;) perhaps Dropbox with a public link? PS: Codepen is one of the clumsiest online code editors I've seen around... why not develop the proper way, on your machine, using i.e: VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

You would need to upload this picture to Codepen, so Codepen can actually access this picture even if your Computer is shut down. Unfortunately, this is a pro feature (bottom-left corner -> "Assets")

**Using a free Webspace:**

However, there are many websites online that provide a free webspace, where you can upload your html, css, images, php files and more and often you also get your own subdomain (like mywebsite.webhost.com).

From the top of my head I only know bplaced.net but feel free to search around.

**Using an image hoster:**

If you want to stay with Codepen and the nice IDE you can look out for an Image Hoster where you can upload your file and get a *direct* link to the image which you can then use on your codepen.

Answer (score 0):

You can download xampp or wampp (if you are on windows) or there are plugins for VSCode to mimic a quck http server. You can do everything on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files in your system to codepen in assests (pro feature). or you can use their own free design asstes